# Simple recursive function f#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

This is an example from my professors book, but when I try to run it in f# it doesn't work. Can someone point out what is wrong here?

```
let rec readNonZeroValue a =
let a = int (System.Console. ReadLine ())
match a with
    |0 ->
        printfn "Error: zero value entered. Try again"
        readNonZeroValue ()
    |_ ->
        a
printfn "Please enter a non-zero value"
let b = readNonZeroValue ()
printfn "You typed: %A" b
```

I am beginner, so sorry for asking such a simple question.

The point of the code is simply for the user to be able to type in a number and then get it printed to the terminal, for any other number than 0.

I have another very similar piece of code that actually works, only difference is that it takes a string instead:

```
let rec progLang a = 
   printfn "Please enter the name of a programming language"
   let a = string (System.Console.ReadLine())
   match a with
   |"Fsharp" -> 
       printfn "%A is cool" a
       progLang ()
   |"quit" -> a
   |_ ->  
       printfn "I don't know %A" a
       progLang ()
```

Comment: Can you include the source code in the question as code, rather than an image? Also, please explain in what way it "does not work" and how are you trying to run this?

Comment: Try deleting the blank in front of `ReadLine`

Comment: It uses `Console.ReadLine`, so you'll need to run this in a compiled console application - running it in F# Interactive would not work.

Comment: Your first function has poor indentation - in F#, white space matters. Is this a copy-paste error? If not, then that is probably the reason. That said, you should also say what error message you are getting, which will help us answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with the function that works.

```
let rec progLang a = 
   printfn "Please enter the name of a programming language"
   let a = string (System.Console.ReadLine())
   match a with
   |"Fsharp" -> 
       printfn "%A is cool" a
       progLang ()
   |"quit" -> a
   |_ ->  
       printfn "I don't know %A" a
       progLang ()
```

"let rec progLang a" is a bit odd because the variable is inferred to be of type Unit, so the code may as well say

```
let rec progLang () = 
   printfn "Please enter the name of a programming language"
   ... etc ...
```

So for the one that doesnt work, you need to ensure the indentation is correct, AND I think the code u have pasted is of a function, plus some code that calls the function, the function should be this (if you're learning it may be an idea to put the type of the function in a comment - I do this quite a lot).

```
// Unit -> int
let rec readNonZeroValue a =
    let a = int (System.Console. ReadLine ())
    match a with
        |0 ->
            printfn "Error: zero value entered. Try again"
            readNonZeroValue ()
        |_ ->
            a
```

So its a function that takes unit and returns an int, and you could potentially call it with code like this:

```
// unit -> unit
let codeThatCalls () = 
    printfn "Please enter a non-zero value"
    let b = readNonZeroValue ()
    printfn "You typed: %A" b
```

The moral of the story is IDENTATION is important, and can completely change the meaning of your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot of the help.
It makes a lot of sense to just use ( ) if the function variable is a unit. 

In the meantime I managed to make a function that works, but your feedback was still very helpful and appreciated.

To the other comments, I will try to make my posts on here more concise in the future, but thanks regardless. :)